# Need help creating complex ef linq select

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello i am having some problems creating an complex Linq with multible joins and left joins.

I have 4 tables as listed in the end, what this is used for is to see how i need to send an email about a new reply to a topic. So i fetch all Posts from the topic joined by the user. The same user can ofcause have more then 1 post in each topic.
After that i join with UserEmailSetting, this is to see if the user have oped out reciving email notifications. Lastly i need to know if an email have been send to the user notifying about the new reply (I don't want to spam my users if there are made a lot of replys), so if an reply notification have been sendt since the last visit to the site I don't want to send another mail. Here is my try that works, but i would like to optimate it!
The problem is that there can be many results on the UserEmailSetting, so i get alot os results back when i infact only get 1 or 2 back.

here is my attept

```
var select = (from p in ForumPostRepository.Get()
              join u in UserRepository.Get() on p.UserId equals u.Id
              join ues in UsersEmailSettingRepository.Get() on u.Id equals ues.UserId

              join els in
                  (from _el in EmailLogRepository.Get()
                   where _el.Type == "ReplyToTopic" &&
                             _el.Values == topicId
                       orderby _el.Id descending 
                       select _el) on u.Id equals els.UserId 
                        into emailLogs

              from el in emailLogs.DefaultIfEmpty()

              where p.TopicId == forumTopic.Id &&
                    ues.ReplyToTopic //&& // We only want people who need notifications
                    //!u.Online // We only want people who are not online

              orderby p.Id descending, el.Id descending
              select new
              {
                  User = u,
                  EmailLog = el
              });

    var result = select.DistinctBy(x => x.User.Id).ToList();
```

Here are the database classes

```
public class ForumPost
{
    public int? TopicId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Online { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class UsersEmailSetting
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public bool ReplyToTopic { get; set; }
}

public class EmailLog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Values { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Updata:** a bit more structured layout of what i want the linq to do, I hope It helps

- Get all posts from ForumPostRepository where topicId is 13
- Join with UserRepository on ForumPostRepository.UserId = UserRepository.Id
- Now I only want unike users
- Join with UsersEmailSettingRepository on UserRepository.Id =
  UsersEmailSettingRepository.UserId
- Left join with EmailLogRepository on UserRepository.Id =
  EmailLogRepository.UserId AND EmailLogRepository.Type =
  “ReplyToTopic” AND EmailLogRepository.Values = “topicId”
- -> Now there can be anywhere from 0 to * results on this request, I only want the latest!

Comment: Sometimes its better to just write SQL than try do something like this.

Comment: Could you show which navigation properties there are in your classes?

Comment: I use a repetory pattern so i do not have access to navigation properties. I will do an update to the question, in 2 min.

Comment: I must note that your EmailLog table is the typical Message Queue in the Database Antipattern. I will have to search the blog post that references common MQ in SQL issues. But you will find that this table grows quickly whilst very little old data is used.

Comment: @Aron my plan is to purge the database for entries older then 1 day.

Comment: http://blog.engineyard.com/2011/5-subtle-ways-youre-using-mysql-as-a-queue-and-why-itll-bite-you

Comment: @DoomStone Repository and navigation properties are not mutually exclusive. Cutting yourself off from using nav properties is like tying your hands behind your back while your forehead is itching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No guarantees that this will be performant.

```
    var users = UserRepository.Get();
    var userEmailSettings = UsersEmailSettingRepository.Get();
    var emailLogs = EmailLogRepository.Get();
    var posts = ForumPostRepository.Get();
    var foo = 
        from user in users
        where posts
               .Any(post => post.UserId == u.Id && post.TopicId == topicId)
        where userEmailSettings
               .Any(ues => u.Id equals ues.UserId && ues.ReplyToTopic == true)
        where false == 
        (
                from el in emailLogs
                where el.Type == "ReplyToTopic"
                && el.Values == topicId
                && el.UserId == user.Id
                && el.Created > user.LastLogin
                select el
        ).Any()
        select user;
```

Signed

A Linq Ninja

edit: just saw that you don't have navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks will try it when i get home

Comment: i have tryed it now, but it dose not work :( i think the linq itself is valid, but i do not think EF knows how to translate it!
Code: http://pastebin.com/XGJhJFdi Error: http://i.imgur.com/asHjXJr.png

Comment: Ah...gotcha...sigh...typical...this should fix it. Apologies. I forgot to closure off the IQueryable as opposed to Repository.Get() Func. This should work, although I warn you that a few EF-Linq providers will not work, like MySQL.

Comment: Luckly should this query not be fired that often, only when a new post is posted, but i can execute sql directly if you think that would be able to give a better result?